# Non linear second order PDE involving max operator (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I'm trying to solve the following Dynamic Programming equation in continuous time ($dt \rightarrow 0$)

$$ v(x,t) = \max\Big\{|x|\,,\,v(x,t)+dt\Big(v_t(x,t)+\frac{1}{2(t+1)}v_{xx}(x,t)\Big) \Big\} - \alpha dt$$

for $x \in [-1,1]$, $t \in [0,T]$ with $v(x,T) = |x|$ and $v(1,t)=v(-1,t)=1 \,\,\forall t$.

Is there a way to properly take the limit where $dt \rightarrow 0$ and arrive to a more conventional PDE? Is this an appropriate way of writing the equation? What would be a more appropriate way, if there is?

The approach I have followed is to take the equation as it is and use an explicit first order Euler method with standard centered second order finite differences for $v_{xx}$, which leads to

$$ v_i^j = \max\Big\{|x^j|\,,\,v_{i+1}^j+\frac{\Delta t}{2{\Delta x}^2(t_{i+1}+1)}(v_{i+1}^{j+1}-2v_{i+1}^{j}+v_{i+1}^{j-1}) \Big\} - \alpha \Delta t$$

where I have defined $t_i \equiv i\Delta t$, $x^j \equiv j\Delta x$, and $v_i^j \equiv v(x^j,t_i)$.

I believe it is producing reasonable solutions for small or moderate values of $\alpha$, but when $\alpha$ gets quite large I need to decrease $\Delta x$, which in turn forces me to decrease $\Delta t$ to maintain stability, and becomes impractical. I'm a bit of a loss on how to implement an implicit method here, given the presence of the max operator.

***Edit:***

I have noticed that the equation can be written as

$$ \alpha = \max\Big\{\frac{|x|-v(x,t)}{dt}\,,\,v_t(x,t)+\frac{1}{2(t+1)}v_{xx}(x,t) \Big\} $$

but I'm not sure if it helps, I don't really know what to do with the first term inside the $\max$

***Edit 2:***

Following @MichaelRenardy 's advice, I wonder if it could be written just like this:

$$ v_t(x,t) = \min\Big\{0,-\frac{1}{2(t+1)}v_{xx}(x,t) + \alpha \Big\} $$

since $v_t = 0$ implies $v = |x|$, and using the notation of obstacle problems, it's clear that $v = |x|$ in the contact region.

Comment: Something seems to be misstated here: If I set dt=0, I just get $v=\max(|x|,v)$, which does not allow us to solve for $v$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy you have to use the inital (or rather final) condition v(T)=|x|. Also, a property of this equation (I'm not quite sure how to show it formally) is that v(x,t)>=|x| for all t. So you would get v=v. But I don't think you can set dt=0, you have to take the limit

Comment: Would this be a more conventional form of your problem: $v-|x|\ge 0$, $v_t-\alpha+\frac{1}{2(t+1)}v_{xx})\le 0$ and $(v-|x|)(v_t-\alpha+\frac{1}{2(t+1)}v_{xx})=0$? Problems like this are called obstacle problems and there is an extensive literature about them.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I was innacurate before, what it's true is that $v(x,t)\ge|x|-\alpha dt$. But could you ellaborate a bit more on how you got to the form you wrote, please? I searched a little about obstacle problems and I guess it makes sense since the equation I posted arises from an optimal stopping problem (it's a Bellman equation).

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I'm sorry to insist but I haven't managed to understand how you arrived to your expression. If you would be so kind as to enlighten me I would really appreciate it, please.

Comment: As you have noted, your original form implies $v\ge |x|-\alpha dt$, which becomes $v\ge |x|$ in the limit $dt\to 0$. If $v$ is strictly greater than $|x|$, we must have $v_t+\frac{1}{2(t+1)}v_{xx}-\alpha=0$, since $v=v$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy do you agree with my proposal at the end of my question? (my 2nd edit)